# Download file one time only for auth user (Suggestion needed)

Tags: views, 7, files

I have a website has a books & categorize each book to unites, each units has a download link..

when user have a role, he can download file just 1 time .. no more for each unit ..

for example:

Book1 --> unit1 --> download --> if(user NOT download) else { Remove Link }

Book1 --> unit2 --> download --> this link was removed since you download a file

Book1 --> unit3 --> download --> if(user NOT download) else { Remove Link }

Book2 --> unit1 --> download --> if(user NOT download) else { Remove Link }

Book2 --> unit2 --> download --> if(user NOT download) else { Remove Link }

Note: books & unit is term, units are child in books.

my idea for solve this issue is create a normal text field and set user id if he click on download link..

Any suggestion for solve a problem, way, or module, field setting ...
thanks every body

Comment: You've stated a fact about how your site work.  What is your question?  Also: If the question just happens to be: "How do I implement this functionality?", please note that this is a Q&A site where developers help each other by answering technical questions, not a free code writing service.

Comment: Dear @FreeRadical, thank you for replay, 

I dont need a code, surly, Im a programmer, and no one programmer like to get code by ask another .. 

Just i ask to get an info if there any drupal 7 module, or field setting to do thats, 

Since I have a one solution in my head.. my idea its create a normal text and set user id if he click on download link ..so, before im work with this idea, Im try to look if any suggestion for solve this problem ..

thanks a lot for replay, I will add to my question this idea .. thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Follow these steps.

1. First use `Private File System`
2. Write your custom module and create a schema/table to trace who has downloaded which file.
3. Implement `hook_file_download($uri)` or `hook_file_download_access_alter(&$grants, $file_item, $entity_type, $entity)` and consult your custom table whether the user has already downled the file or not and provide access accordinlgy, if user hasn't downloaded the file then provide him the access and update your table.
4. Make sure your module runs late, using `weight`.
5. While displaying the download link consult your custom table and show/hide links accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [modules](/questions/tagged/modules) tag if you're looking for a module hosted at Drupal.org.

There exist a module named [Deep Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/deeplink).  With 13 installs and no full release in sight, I wouldn't have high hopes for the usefulness of this, but the project page says:

> Deep link module allows the direct access to a specific item of content under certain circumstances and limitations. Such as one-off or time-limited deeplinks.

There is also [Expiring Private File Link](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bradjmsu/1370844).

It says:

> This module was created when the need arose to offer a downloadable file to users of a site, without revealing the actual URL of the file itself. It also allows through the permissions system a method of allowing the file to only be available for download to registered users. If enabled, anonymous users will see the same dynamic link as registered users, but when they click on it they are presented with a login dialog informing them they must register to have access to the file.

This is a sandbox for Drupal 7, so its usefulness is even more questionable, but you may still want to check it out.

Comment: thank you very much @Free Radical, 

I will try it ....

Also can you till me about your opinion about my idea, its good or bad ..

my idea is set textarea field or user references field, this field will has an user id for each one was clicked on link to download, so preprocess page, i will check if user id exists on field, i will unset link...

thanks,

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to implement some sort of access control scheme vis-a-vis downloadable content, or is to avoid cluttering the UI?  It is impossible to evaluate the idea without understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: oh, Im sorry for that, my English is very bad, I will try for last time, since im stole from you a lot of time ...

I will explain my idea as step 
1) add field type is user referances in unit term
2) when user click on units, i will check if he loggin or no
4) if he loggin I will check if he have a role to download a file
5) if he have a role, i will check field user references in point one, if user exists, thats mean he download a file, so i will remove a download line
6) if user not exists, I will give he a download link, and i will update field, and add new user ...

I hope its more clear

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Anyway, this site is not the right place for getting "opinions". We answer technical question. For "opinions" try one of the dev forums on Drupal.org or another dev oriented social website.